# PyWinAuto : How to find a window launched from one process but owned by another

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto to try to automate some things
Let me present my workflow a little in pseudocode

```
open excel
select add in (WOW.EXE) in menu
click on button in lower ribbon
app opens in a new window running in WOW.EXE
```

For my code I was trying something like this

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="EXCEL.EXE", title="Book 1 - WOW open")

try:
    app.Book1WOWopen.set_focus()
    app.Book1WOWopen.MagicButton.click()
    time.sleep(10)
except: pass

try:
    app2 = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="WOW.exe", title="WOW WOW WOW")
    app2.window(title="WOW WOW WOW").close()
except: pass
```

strangely that doesn't seem to work.
If I look in UIVerify, I can see that the WOW window is hosted under EXCEL's window tree
So I wondered if that meant that it is somehow hidden?

Comment: Just a note, that I can find the windows and close them by a different python based method. I would however like to know how to use pyautogui to solve my issue. I guess it is possible to do so, and that I am just too stupid to work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that WOW window has the same or different process ID in `Inspect.exe` or in UIVerify. It's possible situation when single application has few processes: for example, Calculator on Windows 10 (yes, even Calculator :) ).

One of the possible ways is using `Desktop(backend="uia")` instead of `Application(backend="uia")`. Of course, connect is not necessary then.

```
Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="WOW WOW WOW").close()
```